# How can I translate a multidimensional vector from C++ to Java?

Tags: java, translate, multidimensional-array

So, I completed a project with ease in C++, only to realize I was supposed to write it in Java.  This wouldn't be too big of a deal, except that my code uses multidimensional vectors, like:

```
vector <vector<int> > arr
```

Is there something equivalent in Java that would give the same result without having to drastically rewrite the program?

Here's the code snippet from the C++ program that I am having trouble translating:

```
vector <vector <int> > arr;

cin >> n;

while (n > 0)
{
    vector <int> row;
    int u;

    for (int i = 0; i < n ; ++i)
    {
        cin >> u;
        row.push_back(u);
    }

    arr.push_back(row);

    n = comb(row.size(), k);
    k++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i+=2)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); ++j)
        sum += arr[i][j];

for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i+=2)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); ++j)
        diff += arr[i][j];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) should provide the functionality that you need, if you declare it as an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`. Your calls to `push_back()` are equivalent to calls to [`add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29). You will lose the array index access notation, but this can be resolved by chaining calls to [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks for the information about get().  However, what do you mean by chaining calls to get()?  Do you have a hint as to how I could translate the nested loops I'm using to appropriately use the get() method?

Comment: @TheRationalist As an example, your line `diff += arr[i][j];` would have to become `diff += arr.get(i).get(j)`. The first `get()` returns an `ArrayList<Integer>` and the second returns an `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

you can ArrayList to adapt your code. Here is a small example.

```
 ArrayList <ArrayList<Integer>> aa = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    aa.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    aa.get(0).add(10);
```

edit

your code would look like this

```
    ArrayList <ArrayList<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int n;
    n=br.read();
    while (n>0)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int u;
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            u=br.read();
            row.add(u);

        }
        arr.add(row);
        //I don't know this function
        n=com(row.size(),k);
        k++;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i+=2)
        for (int j=0;j<arr.get(i).size())
            sum+=arr.get(i).get(j);
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you.  If I hadn't already given the selected answer to Thomas, I'd give it to you for sure.  :(

Comment: Another quick question. Does BufferedReader translate directly to integer variables, or does it store the input as a string?  EDIT: OK, it does return an int, I've read, but a better question.  To finish the input in Eclipse, I have to press Ctrl+z.  When this signal is entered, does the BufferedReader object return a -1?  So, would I be storing a -1 as the last element in the last row?

Comment: As a matter of fact I did a mistake. The int returned by read, is the code of the character, not the value. For example if you read 3, it will return 53 or something like that. You can use a String to read into it, and convert it to int with `Integer.parseInt()` like so:  `String s;
             s=br.readLine();
             if (s!=null)
              row.add(Integer.parseInt(s));` This way you will not have unwanted elements in your `ArrayList`

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What I ended up doing was using a Scanner object and the nextInt() function for each integer input. Worked like a charm.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Java got multidimensional vectors too. Just use

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>arr=new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Depending on your version of Java, you may need to instantiate it as `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()`. In Java 7, you can write this as `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arr = new ArrayList<>()`. Your code will generate compiler warnings in all versions of Java.